# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined rails & workers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, web-worker

I have a rails app, and I wanted my ajax call to be done by a worker. So I have a separate js file for my ajax call. I will start the worker upon button click. But every time i click the button an error is occurring:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

The separate token.js file for my ajax:

```
var token = "";
        $.ajax({
                url: "http://xxx.xxx.net/api/tokens.json?email=xxx@xxx.net&password=xxx",
            async: false,
                headers: { "Accept": "application/xml", "Content-Type": "application/xml", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
                var result = data;
                token = result.api_token;
                console.log(token);
                postMessage(token.toString());
            }
    });
```

My store.js is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sync_database").on("click", function(){
        var worker = new Worker("/assets/token-838a808f3bf49df7adf90acc7977c0bba003c3eca36a53b50ac8f9ef6bd5a50f.js");
        worker.onmessage = function (event) {
          alert(event.data);
        };
    });
});
```

My application.js is shown below:

```
//= require jquery-2.0.0.min
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.dataTables.min
//= require turbolinks 
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require selectize.min
//= require store
```

Comment: where is token.js loaded?

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is included? Try adding a `console.log` to document.ready

Comment: Try using `$.noConflict();` or use `jQuery` instead of `$` and check if problem is solved

Comment: It's loaded in the store.js